# How to express {2n+3m+1|n,m∈N} in list comprehension form? (N is the set of natural numbers including 0)

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

How do I express {2n+3m+1|n,m∈N} in list comprehension form? N is the set of natural numbers, including 0.

Comment: This appears to be a homework question, but is not tagged as such.  Please read the corresponding FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230510/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: This is underspecified. Do you want set semantics (i.e., no duplicates) in your answer? Does order matter?

Answer (score 12):

Shortly:

```
1:[3..]
```

Comment: It was asked to use list comprehension.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't {2n+3m+1|n,m ∈ ℕ} = ℕ - {0,2}?

Comment: and 2. You can't get 1 from 2*n + 3*m

Comment: yeah, you're right. but apart from these two, any x > 2 ∈ N can be expressed as 2n+3m+1

Answer (score 8):

The following Haskell function will give you all pairs from two lists, even if one or both is infinite.  Each pair appears exactly once:

```
allPairs :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
allPairs _ [] = []
allPairs [] _ = []
allPairs (a:as) (b:bs) = 
   (a, b) : ([(a, b) | b <- bs] `merge` 
             [(a, b) | a <- as] `merge` 
             allPairs as bs)
  where merge (x:xs) l = x : merge l xs
        merge []     l = l
```

You could then write your list as

```
[2 * n + 3 * m + 1 | (n,m) <- allPairs [0..] [0..] ]
```

To get a feel for how it works, draw an infinite quarter-plane, and look at the results of

```
take 100 $ allPairs [0..] [0..]
```

Comment: it is perhaps worth clarifying that the default fixity in Haskell is `infixl 9` so the nested ```merge``` expression in this answer is associated to the left, i.e. it is parsed as ``( ( [(a, b) | b <- bs] `merge` [(a, b) | a <- as] ) `merge` allPairs as bs)``.

Answer (score 4):

`[2*n + 3*m +1 | m <- [0..], n <- [0..]]` won't work because it starts with `m = 0` and goes through all the `n`, and then has `m = 1` and goes through all the n, etc. But just the `m = 0` part is infinite, so you will never get to m = 1 or 2 or 3, etc. So `[2*n + 3*m +1 | m <- [0..], n <- [0..]]` is exactly the same as `[2*n + 3*0 +1 | n <- [0..]]`.

To generate all of them, you either need to realize, like users vartec and Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil, that the set of numbers you want is just the natural numbers - {0,2}. Or you need to somehow enumerate all the pairs (m,n) such that m,n are nonnegative. One way to do that is to go along each of the "diagonals" where `m + n` is the same. So we start with the numbers where `m + n = 0`, and then the ones where `m + n = 1`, etc. Each of these diagonals has a finite number of pairs, so you will always go on to the next one, and all the pairs (m,n) will eventually be counted.

If we let `i = m + n` and `j = m`, then `[(m, n) | m <- [0..], n <- [0..]]` becomes `[(j, i - j) | i <- [0..], j <- [0..i]]`

So for you, you can just do

```
[2*(i-j) + 3*j +1 | i <- [0..], j <- [0..i]]
```

(Of course this method will also produce duplicates for you because there are multiple (m,n) pairs that generate the same number in your expression.)

Comment: dunno what i was drinking when i posted that answer :P
thanks for the explanation though :) and i will delete my useless post

Comment: You could always `nub` the list in order to eliminate duplicates, although then it's not strictly a list comprehension only, and it'll use inordinate amounts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enumerating all pairs of integers. 
This code is based in the enumeration described at [University of California Berkeley](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math55/pairs.ps) (doesn't include 0)

```
data Pair=Pair Int Int deriving Show

instance Enum Pair where
    toEnum n=let l k=truncate (1/2 + sqrt(2.0*fromIntegral k-1))
                 m k=k-(l k-1)*(l k) `div` 2
             in 
               Pair (m n) (1+(l n)-(m n))
    fromEnum (Pair x y)=x+((x+y-1)*(x+y-2)) `div` 2
```

But you can use another enumeration.

Then you can do:

```
[2*n+3*m+1|Pair n m<-map toEnum [1..]]
```

Answer (score 0):

my 0.2:

```
trans = concat [ f n | n <- [1..]]
 where 
  mklst x = (\(a,b) -> a++b).unzip.(take x).repeat
  f n | n `mod` 2 == 0 = r:(mklst n (u,l))
      | otherwise      = u:(mklst n (r,d))
  u = \(a,b)->(a,b+1)
  d = \(a,b)->(a,b-1)
  l = \(a,b)->(a-1,b)
  r = \(a,b)->(a+1,b)

mkpairs acc (f:fs) = acc':mkpairs acc' fs
                  where acc' = f acc
allpairs = (0,0):mkpairs (0,0) trans          
result = [2*n + 3*m + 1 | (n,m) <- allpairs]
```