# Cartesian product of infinite lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, infinite, cartesian-product

I have a function for finite lists

```
> kart :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
> kart xs ys = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]
```

but how to implement it for *infinite* lists? I have heard something about Cantor and set theory.

I also found a function like

```
> genFromPair (e1, e2) = [x*e1 + y*e2 | x <- [0..], y <- [0..]]
```

But I'm not sure if it helps, because Hugs only gives out pairs without ever stopping.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your first definition, `kart xs ys = [(x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]`, is equivalent to

```
kart xs ys  =  xs >>= (\x ->
               ys >>= (\y -> [(x,y)]))
```

where

```
(x:xs) >>= g  =  g x ++ (xs >>= g)
(x:xs) ++ ys  =  x : (xs ++ ys)
```

are sequential operations. Redefine them as alternating operations,

```
(x:xs) >>/ g  =  g x +/ (xs >>/ g)
(x:xs) +/ ys  =  x : (ys +/ xs)
[]     +/ ys  =  ys
```

and your definition should be good to go for infinite lists as well:

```
kart_i xs ys  =  xs >>/ (\x ->
                 ys >>/ (\y -> [(x,y)]))
```

testing,

```
Prelude> take 20 $ kart_i [1..] [101..]
[(1,101),(2,101),(1,102),(3,101),(1,103),(2,102),(1,104),(4,101),(1,105),(2,103)
,(1,106),(3,102),(1,107),(2,104),(1,108),(5,101),(1,109),(2,105),(1,110),(3,103)]
```

courtesy of ["The Reasoned Schemer"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=10663). (see also [conda, condi, conde, condu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843563/conda-condi-conde-condu/10848902#10848902)).

---

another way, more explicit, is to create separate sub-streams and combine them:

```
kart_i2 xs ys = foldr g [] [map (x,) ys | x <- xs]
  where
     g a b = head a : head b : g (tail a) (tail b)
```

this actually produces exactly the same results. But now we have more control over how we combine the sub-streams. We can [be more diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793597/849891):

```
kart_i3 xs ys = g [] [map (x,) ys | x <- xs]
  where                                       -- works both for finite
  g [] [] = []                                --  and infinite lists
  g a  b  = concatMap (take 1) a
            ++ g (filter (not . null) (take 1 b ++ map (drop 1) a))
                 (drop 1 b)
```

so that now we get

```
Prelude> take 20 $ kart_i3 [1..] [101..]
[(1,101),(2,101),(1,102),(3,101),(2,102),(1,103),(4,101),(3,102),(2,103),(1,104)
,(5,101),(4,102),(3,103),(2,104),(1,105),(6,101),(5,102),(4,103),(3,104),(2,105)]
```

With some [searching on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+pairs+diagonal) I've also  found an [answer by Norman Ramsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762806/849891) with seemingly yet another way to generate the sequence, splitting these sub-streams into four areas - top-left tip, top row, left column, and recursively the rest. His `merge` there is the same as our `+/` here.

---

Your second definition,

```
genFromPair (e1, e2) = [x*e1 + y*e2 | x <- [0..], y <- [0..]]
```

is equivalent to just

```
genFromPair (e1, e2) = [0*e1 + y*e2 | y <- [0..]]
```

Because the list `[0..]` is infinite there's no chance for any other value of `x` to come into play. *This* is the problem that the above definitions all try to avoid.

Comment: Your last output list is missing `(1,105)`. It is still quite impressive. I’ve not had a chance to run Norman Ramsey’s but it looks terrific.
Cartesian products are fascinating. I generated one with `mergeAll` in which any non-duplicate was a prime.

Comment: @fp_mora it's the very next one, try `take 21 $ kart_i3 [1..] [100..]` or `kart_i3 [1..] [100..] !! 20` or `elemIndex (1,105) $ kart_i3 [1..] [100..]`. Haskell's  indices used by `!!` are 0-based. thanks to your question I'll remember about `elemIndex` from now on, hopefully; thanks! (I now realise that it's what I needed to use [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97610/2909), alas, it was lots of trial and error instead, d'oh)

Comment: @will_ness Diagonal’s can use triangular numbers. We always use multiples of 5 or 10 when taking the first part of an infinite list. If we want 20 then `tri n = foldl (+) 1 [2..n]` and `revtn n = floor (sqrt (n*2))` We `revtn 20` and it returns `6` the length of the of the top row. `tri 6` returns `21`, the number of elements in the diagonal and a triangular number. You make Haskell amazing with your Lambda Calculus Generator, replete with ((^x.(x x)) (^x.(x x))).

Answer (score 0):

```
Prelude> let kart = (\xs ys -> [(x,y) | ls <- map (\x -> map (\y -> (x,y))  ys)  xs, (x,y) <- ls])
Prelude> :t kart
kart :: [t] -> [t1] -> [(t, t1)]
Prelude> take 10 $ kart [0..] [1..]
[(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),(0,10)]
Prelude> take 10 $ kart [0..] [5..10]
[(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),(0,10),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8)]
```

Comment: `null $ filter (\(x,y)-> y >0) $ kart [0..] [0..]` gives `False` but `null $ filter (\(x,y)-> x >0) $ kart [0..] [0..]` does not terminate; your `kart` only includes multiple `x`s if `ys` is finite.

Answer (score 0):

you can think of the sequel as

```
0:          (0, 0)
           /      \
1:      (1,0)    (0,1)
       /     \  /     \
2:  (2,0)   (1, 1)   (0,2)
...
```

Each level can be expressed by `level n: [(n,0), (n-1, 1), (n-2, 2), ..., (0, n)]`

Doing this to `n <- [0..]`

We have

```
cartesianProducts = [(n-m, m) | n<-[0..], m<-[0..n]]
```