# Infinite recursion when enumerating all values of a Generic instance

Tags: haskell, strictness, ghc-generics

For [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524531/1346276) of mine, I wrote the following code, providing [diagonally traversed](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html) [`Universe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe.html) instances for enumerable `Generic`s (it's slightly updated from the version there, but uses the same logic):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

import Data.Universe
import Control.Monad.Omega
import GHC.Generics
import Control.Monad (mplus, liftM2)

class GUniverse f where
    guniverse :: Omega (f x)

instance GUniverse U1 where
    guniverse = return U1

instance (Universe c) => GUniverse (K1 i c) where
    guniverse = fmap K1 $ each (universe :: [c])        -- (1)

instance (GUniverse f) => GUniverse (M1 i c f) where
    guniverse = fmap M1 (guniverse :: Omega (f p))

instance (GUniverse f, GUniverse g) => GUniverse (f :*: g) where
    guniverse = liftM2 (:*:) ls rs
        where ls = (guniverse :: Omega (f p))
              rs = (guniverse :: Omega (g p))

instance (GUniverse f, GUniverse g) => GUniverse (f :+: g) where
    guniverse = (fmap L1 $ ls) `mplus` (fmap R1 $ rs)   -- (2)
        where ls = (guniverse :: Omega (f p))
              rs = (guniverse :: Omega (g p))

instance (Generic a, GUniverse (Rep a)) => Universe a where
    universe = runOmega $ fmap to $ (guniverse :: Omega (Rep a x))
```

(`Omega` is probably not related to the problem, but was part of the question.)

This works for most types, even recursive ones like those:

```
data T6 = T6' | T6 T6 deriving (Show, Generic)
data T = A | B T | C T T deriving (Show, Generic)
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Generic, Eq)
```

Examples:

```
*Main> take 5 $ (universe :: [T6])
[T6',T6 T6',T6 (T6 T6'),T6 (T6 (T6 T6')),T6 (T6 (T6 (T6 T6')))]
*Main> take 5 $ (universe :: [T])
[A,B A,B (B A),C A A,B (B (B A))]
*Main> take 5 $ (universe :: [Tree Bool])
[Leaf False,Leaf True,Branch (Leaf False) (Leaf False),Branch (Leaf False) (Leaf True),Branch (Leaf True) (Leaf False)]
```

But note that above types all have their recursive constructors *not at the first place*! In fact (and this is the problem), the following diverges:

```
*Main> data T7 = T7 T7 | T7' deriving (Show, Generic)
*Main> take 5 $ (universe :: [T7])
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

I first thought that maybe there's something with `Omegas`'s evaluation order, but swapping the left and right parts in line `(2)` only makes `T7` work, and `T6` fail, which is what I'd expect as correct behavior.

My current suspicion is that the call to `universe` in line `(1)` is evaluated too early. For example, the following also diverges, while there should be exactly *one* value in the list, which should not even be evaluated:

```
*Main> data T8 = T8 T8  deriving (Show, Generic)
*Main> null $ (universe :: [T8])
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

So, the only instance, `T8 (T8 (...) ... )`, gets evaluated *inside the list*, even though it is not needed! I have no idea where this effect is coming from -- is it the recursive use of its own `Universe` instance? But why, then, do "right recursive" types like `T6` behave correctly, while "left recursive" ones (`T7`) don't?

Is this a strictness issue? If so, in which part of the code? My `Universe` instance? `Generic`? And how to fix it? I use GHC 7.6.3, if that matters.

Comment: You are a cool guy. Thanks for that (;

Comment: You're welcome! I found the problem very interesting myself -- it made me learn generics.

Answer (score 0):

Types like `T8` can't be generated this. Let's look at what the generics version of universe for T8 actually reduces to:

```
t8Universe :: [T8]
t8Universe = fmap T8 t8Universe
```

At no point is a (:) or [] produced. Without another non-recursive constructor to successfully produce there's no way to make progress. `t8Universe` has exactly as many elements as `t8Universe` has, but that's circular, and so evaluation loops.