# Enumerating all pairs of possibly infinite lists

Tags: haskell

I've got two (possibility infinite) lists `[a]` and `[b]`. I would like to construct a (possibly infinite) list containing all pairs `[(a, b)]`, each exactly once. This seems like it ought to be right up Haskell's alley, but I'm stuck.

I started with the classic diagonalization of the rationals:

```
pairs :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
pairs x y =
    let diag (lhs, rhs) = zip lhs $ reverse rhs
    in concatMap diag $ zip (inits x) (inits y)
```

This works by "enumerating the diagonals:" it takes an initial subsequence of (say) length 4 from both lists, reverses one of them, and zips them together. Repeat for all initial subsequences of all lengths, and concatenating all the results. This works when both lists are infinite.

However this fails if either list is finite. The problem is that we stop once we reach the longest diagonal, so the lower-right triangular half of the grid is not enumerated. e.g. `inits [1, 2]` results in `[[1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]`, and we never enumerate the value `(2, 2)`.

So I blurted out a function to generate both forwards and backwards diagonals:

```
inits_bidir :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits_bidir [] = []
inits_bidir x =
    let forwards = tail $ inits x -- skip empty
        backwards = map reverse $ (tail . reverse . tail . inits . reverse) x
    in forwards ++ backwards

pairs :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
pairs x y =
    let diag (lhs, rhs) = zip lhs $ reverse rhs
    in concatMap diag $ zip (inits_bidir x) (inits_bidir y)
```

example:

```
> inits_bidir [1..3]
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```

Now this works if both lists are the same length (possibly infinite). But it fails if one list is longer than the other, because we're still enumerating the diagonals of a square, but our matrix is rectangular.

Before I dig myself in even deeper, is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Why not this: `pairs x y = [(a,b) | a <- x, b <- y ]` ?

Comment: @Sibi: `> take 10 [(a,b) | a <- [1..], b <- [1..]]' => `[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10)]' :(

Comment: This is a duplicate, I'm sure.... looking....

Comment: @Sibi It seems like the OP wants the pairs ordered by diagonals. If `x` and `y` are infinite your solution will always generate pairs with the same `a` (which may be a problem).

Comment: CarstenKönig & Bakuriu Thanks!

Comment: Also have a look at [the Omega monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html). It enumerates all the cases for you, even if they are potentially infinite.

Comment: hi - here is a version where you get the indices - I'm sure someone can adapt this to the general case without using (!!): https://gist.github.com/CarstenKoenig/a50e040a6913d5a1113c

Comment: Also see [this question on enumerating all the values of a data type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515191/how-to-enumerate-a-recursive-datatype-in-haskell/23517557)

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.0/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:-43--42--43-