# Compute next element of list based on previous elements

Tags: haskell

I want to define an infinite list where each element is a function of all the previous elements.

So, the `n+1`th element of the list would be `f [x1, x2, ..., xn]`.

This seems simple, but I cannot seem to get my head around how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: By chance, I just wrote [an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28101516/791604) that does just that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
gen f = xs where xs = map f $ inits xs
```

Or

```
gen f = fix $ map f . inits
```

Comment: You don't actually need `f [] :` or `tail $`, because `inits xs` gives a first element `[]` without looking at `xs`.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other answer, hopefully a little more readable but less laconic:

```
-- "heads f" will generate all of the the prefixes of the inflist
heads f = map ( (flip take) (inflist f) ) [1..]
-- inflist will generate the infinite list
inflist f = ( f [] ) : map f (heads f)

-- test function
sum1 s = 1 + sum s

-- test run
>> take 5 (inflist sum1)
[1,2,4,8,16]
```

Upd:
 As pointed above the `heads` function can be replaced with `inits`, which I wasn't aware of it's existence.

Comment: Note that in versions of GHC before 7.8.4, `inits` is incredibly slow, so your version would  be better. In 7.8.4 and above, `inits` works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unfoldr`:

```
import Data.List

gen :: ([a] -> a) -> a -> [a]
gen f init = unfoldr (\l -> let n = f (reverse l) in (Just (n, n:l))) [init]
```

note this has to reverse the input list each time. You could use `Data.Sequence` instead:

```
import Data.Sequence

genSeq :: (Seq a -> a) -> a -> Seq a
genSeq f init = unfoldr (\s -> let n = f s in (Just (n, s |> n))) (singleton init)
```