# Compute an infinite list of all finite Blurgs

Tags: haskell

Suppose we define the following datatype in Haskell:

```
data Blurg = Blub
           | Zarg
           | Parg Blurg Blurg
```

This means that `Zarg`, `Parg Blub (Parg Zarg Zarg)`, `Parg (Parg Blub Blub) (Parg Blub Blub)`, etc., are all examples of `Blurgs`.

Now an old exam question is as follows:

> Define a function which will compute a list of all Blurgs.

So I tried:

```
allBlurg' :: [Blurg] -> [Blurg]
allBlurg' sofar = sofar ++ allBlurg' [Parg x y | x <- sofar, y <- sofar]

allBlurg :: [Blurg]
allBlurg = allBlurg' [Blub, Zarg]
```

At first I thought this was a solution, but then I realized that not all possible `Blurgs` are included in the resulting list `allBlurg`. Can someone write a proper solution?

By the way, I'd just like to note that what the problem asks for won't really be a function since it doesn't take any arguments; it should be considered a value instead. Second, although the question doesn't explicitly say so, I think it should be a condition that each `Blurg` only appears once in the list. Also please note that the problem really should only ask for finite Blurgs as user zch has mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I think it's not possible. There is uncountable number of binary trees. Your method generates all finite Blurgs, but there is no way to fit all infinite Blurgs into a list.

Comment: Another problem is that most Blurgs are actually uncomputable, so there is no way to define them in Haskell.

Comment: @zch: I think there is an infinite but countable number of binary trees, but either way I don't think that it is relevant here. At any rate, think about the question like this: if you give me an arbitrary Blurg, it should be contained in the list.

Comment: there is countable number of finite binary trees (and your function generate all of them, including your example), but number of infinite trees is uncountable. You could easily encode digits of a real number on an infinite branch of binary tree. This means that there is no one-to-one function from Blurgs into natural numbers. Likewise, you could contain solution of halting problem on an infinite branch.

Comment: @zch: I take it the task was meant as “compute a list of all _finite_ `Blurg`s”.

Comment: @zch: It's good that you bring this up because I felt like it was clear by context that the problem was only about finite Blurgs - as you said, most infinite Blurgs wouldn't even be computable. I'll update the question so that this is clear, thanks for the note. But I don't think it's true that my list will contain the example I gave above, the Blurgs "Blub" and "Parg (Parg Blub Blub) Blub" will never be together in the list "sofar" at the same recursive call.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515191/how-to-enumerate-a-recursive-datatype-in-haskell

Comment: @chi: While a similar problem, it does not look like a duplicate to me.

Comment: The difference is very thin, in my opinion: the other question asked explicitly how to do that using the Omega monad, while this question asks about how to do it in general. The only other minor difference is that they have a slightly different recursive type.

Comment: chi: For me those differences are substantial: I am not especially interested in seeing how to solve this problem with a library function since I won't have access to those when I need to solve similar problems on an upcoming exam, which is why I asked for a general solution. And that the other problem uses a different recursive type makes it, well, a different problem. But it's still useful to see that link, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @leftaroundabout explained the problem - in your solution `x` never matches anything beyond the first element, because `y` has infinite number of elements to match.

Here is more elementary solution to this problem:

```
nextDepth :: [Blurg] -> [Blurg] -> [Blurg]
nextDepth ls ms =
    [Parg x y | x <- ls, y <- ms] ++
    [Parg x y | x <- ms, y <- ls ++ ms]

deeper :: [Blurg] -> [Blurg] -> [Blurg]
deeper ls ms = ms ++ deeper (ls ++ ms) (nextDepth ls ms)

allBlurg :: [Blurg]
allBlurg = deeper [] [Blub, Zarg]
```

To avoid problem with infinite iteration I use lists with trees of various depths.

`nextDepth` takes a list of trees with depth `< n` and list of trees of depth `== n` and returns trees of depth `== n + 1` that can be constructed from them.

`deeper` for similar arguments returns trees of depth `>= n` (except for infinite ones).

Answer (score 9):

Basically, we need this list:

```
Blub : Zarg : [ Parg x y | {- `x`,`y` from all possible `Blurg` values -} ]
```

Well, actually you can write this out just like that in Haskell:

```
allBlurg :: [Blurg]
allBlurg = Blub : Zarg : [ Pargs x y | x<-allBlurg, y<-allBlurg ]
```

BTW this is *not* a function, though the definition is recursive. In Haskell, values can be recursive!

Perhaps the above is actually what was expected in the task. Trouble is, it's actually wrong: *not* all `Blurg` values will be contained! The reason being, `y<-allBlurg` has to work through an infinite list. It will never get to the end, therefore `x` will stay forever at the first element. I.e., with that “solution”, you'll actually only get lists of the form

```
   Pargs Blub . Pargs Blub . Pargs Blub . Pargs Blub ... Pargs Blub $ x
```

but never `Pargs x y` with some `x` apart from `Blub`.

What's needed to solve this problem: enumerate combinations from two infinite lists. That's the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function), a Haskell implementation is available [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}
import Control.Monad.Omega

allBlurg :: [Blurg]
allBlurg = Blub : Zarg : runOmega [ Pargs x y | x <- each allBlurg
                                              , y <- each allBlurg ]
```

> GHCi> :set -XMonadComprehensions 
>   GHCi> :m +Control.Monad.Omega 
>   GHCi> let allG = B : Z : runOmega [ P x y | x <‌- each allG, y <‌- each allG ]
>   GHCi> take 100 allG
>       [B, Z, P B B, P B Z, P Z B, P B (P B B), P Z Z, P (P B B) B,
>        P B (P B Z), P Z (P B B), P (P B B) Z, P (P B Z) B, P B (P Z B),
>        P Z (P B Z), P (P B B) (P B B), P (P B Z) Z, P (P Z B) B,
>        P B (P B (P B B)), P Z (P Z B), P (P B B) (P B Z), P (P B Z) (P B B),
>        P (P Z B) Z, P (P B (P B B)) B, P B (P Z Z), P Z (P B (P B B)),
>        P (P B B) (P Z B), P (P B Z) (P B Z), P (P Z B) (P B B),
>        P (P B (P B B)) Z, P (P Z Z) B, P B (P (P B B) B), P Z (P Z Z),
>        P (P B B) (P B (P B B)), P (P B Z) (P Z B), P (P Z B) (P B Z),
>        P (P B (P B B)) (P B B), P (P Z Z) Z, P (P (P B B) B) B,
>        P B (P B (P B Z)), P Z (P (P B B) B), P (P B B) (P Z Z),
>        P (P B Z) (P B (P B B)), P (P Z B) (P Z B), P (P B (P B B)) (P B Z),
>        P (P Z Z) (P B B), P (P (P B B) B) Z, P (P B (P B Z)) B,
>        P B (P Z (P B B)), P Z (P B (P B Z)), P (P B B) (P (P B B) B),
>        P (P B Z) (P Z Z), P (P Z B) (P B (P B B)), P (P B (P B B)) (P Z B),
>        P (P Z Z) (P B Z), P (P (P B B) B) (P B B), P (P B (P B Z)) Z,
>        P (P Z (P B B)) B, P B (P (P B B) Z), P Z (P Z (P B B)),
>        P (P B B) (P B (P B Z)), P (P B Z) (P (P B B) B), P (P Z B) (P Z Z),
>        P (P B (P B B)) (P B (P B B)), P (P Z Z) (P Z B),
>        P (P (P B B) B) (P B Z), P (P B (P B Z)) (P B B), P (P Z (P B B)) Z,
>        P (P (P B B) Z) B, P B (P (P B Z) B), P Z (P (P B B) Z),
>        P (P B B) (P Z (P B B)), P (P B Z) (P B (P B Z)),
>        P (P Z B) (P (P B B) B), P (P B (P B B)) (P Z Z),
>        P (P Z Z) (P B (P B B)), P (P (P B B) B) (P Z B),
>        P (P B (P B Z)) (P B Z), P (P Z (P B B)) (P B B), P (P (P B B) Z) Z,
>        P (P (P B Z) B) B, P B (P B (P Z B)), P Z (P (P B Z) B),
>        P (P B B) (P (P B B) Z), P (P B Z) (P Z (P B B)),
>        P (P Z B) (P B (P B Z)), P (P B (P B B)) (P (P B B) B),
>        P (P Z Z) (P Z Z), P (P (P B B) B) (P B (P B B)),
>        P (P B (P B Z)) (P Z B), P (P Z (P B B)) (P B Z),
>        P (P (P B B) Z) (P B B), P (P (P B Z) B) Z, P (P B (P Z B)) B,
>        P B (P Z (P B Z)), P Z (P B (P Z B)), P (P B B) (P (P B Z) B),
>        P (P B Z) (P (P B B) Z), P (P Z B) (P Z (P B B)),
>        P (P B (P B B)) (P B (P B Z)), P (P Z Z) (P (P B B) B)]

Now, actually this is *still* incomplete: it's actually just the list of all *finite-depth* `Blurgs`. As zch remarks, most `Blurg`s are uncomputable, there's no chance to actually enumerate *all* of them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But my compiler cannot parse the word `each`, are you sure you meant to have that there?

Comment: `each` is just another function, defined in the `Control.Monad.Omega` module.

Comment: I'm not a fan of mixing omega and lists in that way. I'd rather keep everything inside omega as much as possible and escaping from that at the end. You can also use `Alternative` as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515191/how-to-enumerate-a-recursive-datatype-in-haskell

Comment: @chi: I kinda agree about better staying with the same container, however in this case it's not really a problem – at least performance-wise, because `Omega` is in fact nothing but a newtype wrapper around a list. And IMO, the combination of monad comprehension and `each` is actually extremely readable and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach: start with a leaf node and a function that expands one leaf node into a tree. The code I'm about to include is a slight variation but the same basic idea.

```
allBlurgs = ab [Blub] where
  ab (a:r) = a : (r ++ expand a)
  expand Blub = [Zarg, Parg Blub Blub]
  expand Zarg = []
  expand (Parg a b) = [Parg a' b | a' <- expand a] ++ [Parg a b' | b' <- expand b]
```