# SICP exercise 3.67 - producing all pairs of integers without restrictions

Tags: stream, scheme, lisp, infinite, sicp

From SICP:

This is an infinite stream of ones:

```
 (define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

This is an infinite stream of positive integers:

```
 ; add-streams takes two streams and produces a stream of their elementwise sum
 (define integers (cons-stream 1 (add-streams ones integers)))
```

`interleave` takes elements alternately from two streams and returns the result

```
(define (interleave s1 s2)
  (if (stream-null? s1)
      s2
      (cons-stream 
       (stream-car s1)
       (interleave s2 (stream-cdr s1)))))
```

The following `pairs` procedure takes two streams `s` and `t`, and produces all pairs `(s_i, t_j)` such that `i <= j`.

```
(define (pairs s t)
  (cons-stream
   (list (stream-car s) (stream-car t))
   (interleave
    (stream-map (lambda (x) 
                  (list (stream-car s) x))
                (stream-cdr t))
    (pairs (stream-cdr s) (stream-cdr t)))))
```

So

```
 (pairs integers integers)
```

produces all pairs of integers `i` and `j` with `i <= j`.

Here is exercise 3.67:

> Exercise 3.67: Modify the `pairs` procedure so that `(pairs integers`
>   `integers)` will produce the stream of all pairs of integers `(i, j)`
>   (without the condition `(i <= j)`). Hint: You will need to mix in an
>   additional stream.

My solution is:

```
(define (pairs2 s t)
  (cons-stream
   (list (stream-car s) (stream-car t))
   (interleave
    (stream-map (lambda (x) 
                  (list (stream-car s) x))
                (stream-cdr t))
    (pairs2 (stream-cdr s) t))))
```

So, I just changed `(stream-cdr t)` to `t` in the last recursive call. This appears to produce all pairs of integers.

What I don't understand is the statement:

> Hint: You will need to mix in an additional stream.

What does this mean? Is my solution wrong? What do they mean when they say an additional stream?

Using my modified `pairs2` procedure, these are the first 20 results:

```
> (define p2 (pairs2 integers integers))
> (stream-ref p2 0)
(1 1)
> (stream-ref p2 1)
(1 2)
> (stream-ref p2 2)
(2 1)
> (stream-ref p2 3)
(1 3)
> (stream-ref p2 4)
(2 2)
> (stream-ref p2 5)
(1 4)
> (stream-ref p2 6)
(3 1)
> (stream-ref p2 7)
(1 5)
> (stream-ref p2 8)
(2 3)
> (stream-ref p2 9)
(1 6)
> (stream-ref p2 10)
(3 2)
> (stream-ref p2 11)
(1 7)
> (stream-ref p2 12)
(2 4)
> (stream-ref p2 13)
(1 8)
> (stream-ref p2 14)
(4 1)
> (stream-ref p2 15)
(1 9)
> (stream-ref p2 16)
(2 5)
> (stream-ref p2 17)
(1 10)
> (stream-ref p2 18)
(3 3)
> (stream-ref p2 19)
(1 11)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your answer is indeed correct. For what is worth, I was able to solve it using one extra stream, which is what the authors meant with the hint "You will need to mix in an additional stream":

```
(define (pairs s t)
  (cons-stream
   (list (stream-car s) (stream-car t))
   (interleave (stream-map (λ (x) (list (stream-car s) x))
                           (stream-cdr t))
               (interleave (stream-map (λ (x) (list x (stream-car t)))
                                       (stream-cdr s))
                           (pairs (stream-cdr s) (stream-cdr t))))))
```

My first 20 results are similar, although in some cases in different order or with different elements that will probably appear later on in your solution:

```
(1 1)
(1 2)
(2 1)
(1 3)
(2 2)
(1 4)
(3 1)
(1 5)
(2 3)
(1 6)
(4 1)
(1 7)
(3 2)
(1 8)
(5 1)
(1 9)
(2 4)
(1 10)
(6 1)
(1 11)
```

Comment: there are, of course, much more ways to mix the streams, e.g. interleave the top row with the left column *first*, and then interleave the result of this with the interleaved rest, i.e. with the core of the matrix. then there's also the full diagonalization, going by the ascending left-to-right diagonals (or equally, the descending right-to-left diagonals, i.e. the same diagonals, just in reversed order). this "matrix" we get by putting elements of `s` in its left column, top-to-bottom, and elements of `t` in its top row, left-to-right, and then filling up the squares.

Comment: relevant search terms: dovetailing, interleaving, diagonalizing (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20516638/849891)), "Omega monad" (in Haskell; there's also the "universe" package which does much the same thing). I think the order that you use in this answer is the same as Norman Ramsey used, in an answer which I mention in the linked answer. Maybe I'll add an answer with the diagonalization in Scheme, here.

Comment: @Óscar López before reading your answer, I also came up with a solution involving another stream. We are almost the same except for the second stream-map. My second stream-map is: (stream-map (λ (x) (list (stream-car s) x)) (stream-cdr t)). We just reversed s and t. Would there be any differences?

Comment: @morbidCode great work! My guess is that the order of the sequence could be different, but that’s irrelevant

Comment: I took a shot at this one too, but got stuck. I couldn't think of a way to do it with `stream-interleave`. Thanks for sharing.