# Haskell method that creates infinite list with all combinations of a given list

Tags: list, haskell, combinations, infinite

My Problem is that I want to create a infinite list of all combinations of a given list. So for example:

```
infiniteListComb [1,2] = [[],[1],[2], [1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2], [1,1,1], ...].
```

other example:

```
infiniteListComb [1,2,3] = [[], [1], [2], [3], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[1,1,1], ...].
```

Reminds me of power sets, but with lists with same elements in it.
What I tried:
I am new in Haskell. I tried the following:

```
infiniteListComb: [x] -> [[x]]
infiniteListComb [] = []
infiniteListComb [(x:xs), ys] = x : infiniteListComb [xs,ys]
```

But that did not work because it only sumed up my list again. Has anyone another idea?

Comment: The code that you've tried doesn't work because the typing is completely wrong (you take in a list of lists yet your typing states that it should be able to take in a list of any value) and it doesn't even have valid syntax.

Comment: The pattern `[(x:xs),ys]` matxhes a list of lists, not a list of items.

Answer (score 5):

We iteratively add the input list `xs` to a list, starting with the empty list, to get the ever growing lists of repeated `xs` lists, and we put each such list of *0, 1, 2, ...* `xs` lists through `sequence`, concatting the resulting lists:

```
infiniteListComb :: [a] -> [[a]]
infiniteListComb xs  =  sequence =<< iterate (xs :) []
            -- = concatMap sequence (iterate (xs :) [])
```

e.g.

```
> take 4 (iterate ([1,2,3] :) [])
[[],[[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]]

> sequence [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]

> take 14 $ sequence =<< iterate ([1,2,3] :) []
[[],[1],[2],[3],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3],[1,1,1]]
```

The essence of Monad is flatMap (splicing map).

*`sequence`* is the real magician here. It is equivalent to

```
sequence [xs, ys, ..., zs] =
  [ [x,y,...,z] | x <- xs, y <- ys, ..., z <- zs ]
```

or in our case

```
sequence [xs, xs, ..., xs] =
  [ [x,y,...,z] | x <- xs, y <- xs, ..., z <- xs ]
```

Coincidentally, `sequence . replicate n` is also known as `replicateM n`. But we spare the repeated counting from 0 to the growing `n`, growing them by 1 at a time instead.

We can inline and fuse together all the definitions used here, including

```
concat [a,b,c...] = a ++ concat [b,c...]
```

to arrive at a recursive solution.

---

Another approach, drawing on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65374357/849891) by [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi),

```
combs xs = ys where 
    ys = [[]] ++ weave [ map (x:) ys | x <- xs ] 
    weave ((x:xs):r) = x : weave (r ++ [xs])
```

There are [many ways](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97539/lambda-calculus-generator/97610#97610) to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516402/cartesian-product-of-infinite-lists-in-haskell/20516638#20516638) `weave`.

Answer (score 4):

Others already provided a few basic solutions. I'll add one exploiting the [`Omega` monad](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.26/control-monad-omega-0.3.2/Control-Monad-Omega.html).

The `Omega` monad automatically handles all the interleaving among infinitely many choices. That is, it makes it so that `infiniteListComb "ab"` does not return `["", "a", "aa", "aaa", ...]` without ever using `b`. Roughly, each choice is scheduled in a fair way.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Omega
       
infiniteListComb :: [a] -> [[a]]
infiniteListComb xs = runOmega go
   where
   go =         -- a combination is
      pure []   -- either empty
      <|>       -- or
      (:) <$>   -- a non empty list whose head is
         each xs  -- an element of xs
         <*>      -- and whose tail is
         go       -- a combination
```

Test:

```
> take 10 $ infiniteListComb [1,2]
[[],[1],[1,1],[2],[1,1,1],[2,1],[1,2],[2,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[2,2]]
```

The main downside of `Omega` is that we have no real control about the order in which we get the answers. We only know that all the possible combinations are there.

Answer (score 3):

Since list Applicative/Monad works via a cartesian-product like system, there's a short solution with `replicateM`:

```hs
import Control.Monad

infiniteListComb :: [x] -> [[x]]
infiniteListComb l = [0..] >>= \n -> replicateM n l
```

Comment: ``infiniteListComb l = [0..] >>= (`replicateM` l)``

Comment: How is replicateM defined?

Comment: @ImkerWarze You can pursue codes [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#replicateM).

Comment: @ImkerWarze `replicateM :: Int -> m a -> m [a]` essentially repeats a monadic action a certain amount of times, collecting intermediate results. You can [find it on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM), along with its [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#replicateM).